# Windows form chart series formatting

Tags: powershell, forms, charts, powershell-studio

Im trying to color the bars weather or not the 'Daily Profit/Loss' value is above Zero or below.  I Feel my problem lies in the foreach statement, but can't quite pinpoint.

Any help is appreciated.  Thank you

Clear-Chart $chart1

```
        $script:csv = Import-Csv -Path "C:\testpath\AutoBotStatsCollected.csv"
    
        update-Chart $chart1 -XPoints $csv.'Market' -YPoints $csv.'Daily Profit/Loss'
        
        $points = $Chart1.Series[0].Points
        
        ForEach($series in $points)
        {
            if ($series -lt 0)
            {
                $chart1.Series[0].Color = 'blue'
            }
            else
            {
                $chart1.Series[0].Color = 'crimson'
            }
        }
```

Comment: How can a series be less than zero?  $series -lt 0

Comment: A negative number

Comment: A series is a line in the graph that has more than one point (an array).  From : $chart1.Series[0].Color = 'blue' To : $series.Color = 'blue'